# JButton Windows Look and Feel

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, look-and-feel

I want get this appearance for a JButton:

[image: lookandfeel1]

I have tried to change the Look and Feel to Windows this way:

```
  UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
```

but it is shown as:

[image: lookandfeel2]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just a stupid question... are you running the program on windows? (Also, if you try to change it on run time, you'd need to call `SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI()`).

Comment: Yes, I'm on Windows. That is the first line in main function.

Comment: OK. No good idea then. (Though I'd use `UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName()` rather than a hard coded name for portability).

Comment: Use `UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());`  Or rather, what @kiheru beat me to - +1.

Comment: The outcome looks like Windows Classic instead of Windows L&F: `com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsClassicLookAndFeel`. Agree with `getSystemLookAndFeelClassName()`.

Comment: I have changed to `getSystemLookAndFeelClassName()` but it remains with the same appearance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking the comment train to a standalone answer:

```
    // sets the look and feel to be that of the operating system's
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | 
        InstantiationException | 
        IllegalAccessException | 
        UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I upvoted kiheru, but it seems like you're not setting it at the right time. **You need to run this code before the components are displayed** - I usually insert this into the original run() method that starts my application, though it varies if I include a splashscreen.

Also, in future (*especially* when talking about GUI code, which can get horrendous) people prefer it if you post runnable code examples, so we can see exactly where you might be getting things wrong :)

Comment: ***"You need to run this code before the components are displayed"***  Either that or update the component tree as seen in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556).

Comment: That's a nifty note; I'm not sure when people would want to use this (compatibility mode design? Perhaps), but that's something new to bookmark!